# How to open any doc file in popup window in php?

Tags: php, jquery, css, doc

I am trying to open any doc file in pop window but every time it automatically download in system. I need to instead of  downloading file by clicking, it should come in popup window.
I am using php for this.

Is there is any jquery plugin to do same. I foud plugin for open image file in popup window but bot for doc file or any other file.

Please let me know if you do know.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: use `window.open()` in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try this for some text in popup window:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open3

Comment: No it is not working as i need. Again it download doc file rather than opening in popup window. I want to show all content of doc in popup window